# CALayer: Custom animatable properties that update built in animatable properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calayer, cabasicanimation

I'm creating a custom animatable property on a `CAGradientLayer` derived class that has to change other built in animatable properties on the `CAGradientLayer` base class and was wondering what the best approach is. Currently I'm updating the dependant properties in the display method:

```
@implementation CustomGradientLayer

@dynamic myCustomProperty;

+ (BOOL) needsDisplayForKey: (NSString*)aKey
{
    BOOL needsDisplay = [aKey isEqualToString: @"myCustomProperty"];
    if (!needsDisplay)
    {
        needsDisplay = [super needsDisplayForKey: aKey];
    }
    return needsDisplay;
}

- (void) display
{
    CGFloat myCustomProperty = [self.presentationLayer myCustomProperty];


    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];

    // Update dependant properties on self

    [CATransaction commit];

    [super display];
}
```

Is it possible to safely update the dependant properties in a custom property setter instead without affecting the underlying `CALayer` magic?

Comment: afaik you can use KVO

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but for anyone interested you can use the following method without interfering with the CALayar stuff:

```
- (void) didChangeValueForKey: (NSString*)aKey (void) didChangeValueForKey: (NSString*)aKey
{
    // Update dependent properties
}
```